# gzip "No space left on device"

Tags: hard-drive, gzip, df

Using gzip 1.3.12 / ubuntu 64bit I am getting "No space left on device" yet there appears to be plenty of disk space remaining.

```
gunzip 03-05-2012--22-52-01.tar.gz

gzip: 03-05-2012--22-52-01.tar: No space left on device
```

If you run the above gunzip twice in a row the first time it takes a while before showing the error, the second time it happens straight away.

On the other hand if I use `tar` it works to start with for a certain number of files before giving errors. After the errors I can see some of the files on disk.

```
tar -zxvf 03-05-2012--22-52-01.tar.gz

<snip>
tar: root/backups/project_x/03-05-2012--22-52-01/data/contentstore/2012/3/29/10/11: Cannot mkdir: No space left on device
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Diskspace:

```
sudo du -sh /* | sort -gr | head -n 5
752M    /usr
424M    /var
160K    /run
78M     /lib
48K     /tmp

df -i -h
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1              640K     75K    566K   12% /
udev                    932K     381    932K    1% /dev
tmpfs                   934K     255    934K    1% /run
none                    934K       2    934K    1% /run/lock
none                    934K       1    934K    1% /run/shm
/dev/xvdb                27M      11     27M    1% /mnt

df -h --total
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1            9.9G  6.3G  3.1G  68% /
udev                  3.7G  4.0K  3.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs                 1.5G  160K  1.5G   1% /run
none                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                  3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /run/shm
/dev/xvdb             414G  199M  393G   1% /mnt
total                 432G  6.5G  405G   2%

sudo blkid
/dev/xvda1: LABEL="cloudimg-rootfs" UUID="46e0a6b7-bb53-4d56-aba0-a2a6202d9787" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/xvdb: UUID="a7534fe5-1538-4ebc-b553-7dfc6a37df02" TYPE="ext3" 
/dev/xvdc: UUID="a7534fe5-1538-4ebc-b553-7dfc6a37df02" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3"
```

Comment: how big is the compressed file (or rather, how big is supposed to be when it's uncompressed?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What is the question you are asking exactly?

> “No space left on device”

Would indicate that you've run out of disk space. Change the current working directory to another directory mounted on a larger partition and try again ...

Also, bear in mind that `du` won't always match `df`. It is possible for files to be deleted but the handles still remain in use by an application, so `df` can show less disk space available than `du` reports.

Comment: I have updated the question to actually ask a question, thanks. I'm in the root users home directory, I also tried copying and unzipping from /tmp with the same error. If I reboot the machine that should close any handles?

Comment: Yes that is likely (but restarting a server should be a last resort). You could find the application that is still holding it open using `lsof` - then you just need to restart/kill that application.

Answer (score 2):

`"No space left on device"`

This error can also indicate permission issues.  Check that your are executing the command as the appropriate user.  Obviously `/root/` requires root permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It was permissions in my case. Anyone facing this issue must check for the file permissions first and the owner.